# Using Compass style library without their command line tool

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm working on a web application. We already have a build process that compiles our `.scss` files into a final `.css` stylesheet. We'd like to adopt compass, and use their semantic blueprint mixins.

However, compass seems to want to "own" the project structure. I already have a build tool (brunch), and just want to use compass' mixins, not their whole workflow.

**Is there a way to access Compass' mixins from vanilla SASS?**

or, alternatively,

**Is there a way to limit Compass' command line tool to *only* do the `.scss` files, and leave my images and javascript alone?**

Comment: Exactly what is wrong with the Compass project structure?  You *can* configure the input/output directories.

Comment: The point is that I already have a project; I already have a build tool; I'm already using Sass; I just want to access the Compass mixins, not re-work my project to match a different tool.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need but here's what I do:

I have a custom compass_config.rb where I set the paths exactly how I want them:

```rb
http_path       = '/'
sass_dir        = 'your/sass/path'
css_dir         = 'your/css/path'
images_dir      = 'your/image/path'
javascripts_dir = 'your/javascript/path'
```

Then I use the compass command line tool with the following parameters: `compass compile --sass-dir other/sass/path/stylesheets --css-dir other/css/path/stylesheets -c path/to/compass_config.rb`

It may seem silly but the important thing here is that you can:

1. Configure the default paths as you need them in your `compass_config.rb` (of course you can name this file as you wish)
2. Tell exactly to compass what it needs to perform when executed through command options
3. You can use `watch` instead od `compile` to continuously poll for changes and compile when they happen

Please have a look at `compass -h`, `compass help compile` or [here](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/).

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I ended up doing. I wish Compass was just a library of Sass mixins, and not also a build tool.

Comment: What would be the purpose of that?  If it were just a set of files to download, you'd have to copy/paste it into every single project (forcing you to keep track of updating the Compass library files every time there is a new version).

Comment: @cimmanon: Right now, I have to let `compass` (the tool) take over my whole project. I have other things to build, too. Best would be if I could declare an explicit dependency on it, without importing, and without using their tool. Also, I want a pony.

Comment: How is using `compass` as a command any different than using `sass`?  They both compile and they both watch.

Comment: Sass can read and write to standard IO, not just files. Sass can be run in syntax check mode. Compass wants to do my javascript and images, too. Sass can be integrated into an existing build process easily; Compass wants to own the build process.

Comment: Compass only cares about where JS files live for instances where a Compass extension contains them, and only so that it knows where to unpack them to.  It only needs to know the image directory if you're using the image helper functions (and again, so that it knows where to unpack images contained within extensions).  Compass is no more a "build tool" than Sass is.

Comment: `compass` is unnecesary for a lot of projects, especially ones where the only point is sprites (which was previously a seperate plugin that was integrated into compass and just killed). The biggest downside to compass is that its just a fancy "alias to sass with sprites" at this point for everyone I know who uses it, because it's "libraries" the reason you would use compass to begin with are either old or unnecessary anymore (given things like autoprefixer), assuming anyone ever used them. The whole design of having a "monolithic library" is just flawed to begin with.

Comment: @srcspider I absolutelly agree with you. If someone used Compass only for sprites I'd say he should look for a tool to solve only that specific problem.